# How can I forward an outlook mail of class ReportItem

Tags: api, outlook, report

The outlook API doesn't allow me to Reply / Forward Report Item.

```
dynamic mail = _application.Session.GetItemFromID(emailEntryId);
OlObjectClass olClass = (OlObjectClass)mail.Class;
if(olClass== OlObjectClass.olReport){
    mail.Forward();
}
```

With MailItem I perform forwarding with ReportItem I can't.

How can I do that? Basically I want to forward (a class of mail) of  content of undeliverable ReportItem.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly create a `MailItem` object and populate its properties. Or you can create a new `MailItem` object and add `ReportItem` as an attachment.

Comment: Can you provide an example or a link to an example?

Comment: Which part are you having problem with? What is your existing code?

Comment: I get chinese in the email body :

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040321/outlook-reportitem-body-returning-messed-up-encoding-for-some-users