# VSTO ReportItem.Body appeared garbled

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

Here is the question. I'm developing a VSTO add-in for OUTLOOK to read bounce back email.
While I get the string Body from ReportItem, it displays garbled text.

I used outlookspy to check the value, it is garbled. Is anyone know how to fix it?
[image]

Here is my code:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
foreach (object item in inbox.Items)
{
    Outlook.ReportItem mail = item as Outlook.ReportItem;
    string Bodystring = mail.Body;

    // DO something
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Chinese is really just a parsing issue in OOM. You need to parse the string to proper coding, for example, in VBA you may try to use the following code:

```
Dim strBody as String
strBody = StrConv(Report.Body, vbUnicode)
```

Also, you can use Redemption to get the text encoded correctly:

```
set rItem = oSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(oItem)
MsgBox rItem.ReportText
```

See [Outlook ReportItem.Body returning messed up encoding for some users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040321/outlook-reportitem-body-returning-messed-up-encoding-for-some-users) for more information.

Comment: this example is about VBA, could I apply it on VSTO?

Comment: Yes. The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is it the correct way to handle. the problem can be solved by the following code:

```
string body = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mail.body)));
```

and I write the mail body to txt file. It is html.

[image]

But any other problem happened.

After processing the email. the mail content garbled.

before
[image]
After:
[image]