# How to extract Error-Code from REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR outlook object using Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation, mapi

I am trying to extract certain details from an outlook mailbox. I want to extract bounced emails and get the error code of why these emails were bounced.

I know with using regular expression I can extract that from the body of the message. but I am wondering if there is a MAPI ID that I can use or an existing property that can give me this error code straightaway instead of having to process the body?

I was able to use this to extract receivers email,

```
print(message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001E")) #receiver address
```

I got that ID from the solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284859/retrieve-email-address-from-outlooks-undeliverable-email-using-vba) and it shows that we can use other MAPI ids to extract certain details about the email. I am wondering if there is an ID that extracts the error code from REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR same way. Seems like a logical attribute to have but somehow I cannot find it anywhere.

I asked GPT and it gave me this ID

"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1001F001"

I tried using it but I am getting this error

```
com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)
```

I also understand that IDs beyond certain range cannot be retrieved via the PropertyAccessor.

Any recommendations that is more straightforward than using a regex on the body?

Answer (score 0):

`0x1001F001` is not a valid proptag. If you mean `0x1001001F`, it is `PR_REPORT_TEXT`, but it is only available for the recipients in the message recipient table. Normally, you can loop through the `Recipients` collection and access that property for each recipient using `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`, but the `ReportItem` object in the Outlook Object Model does not expose the `Recipients` collection like `MailItem` object does:

[image]

You can either try to extract the data from the `ReportItem.Body` property (it is constructed dynamically by Outlook from the NDR recipients collection), or use an Extended MAPI wrapper like [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) to access the NDR as a [ReportItem](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOReportItem.htm) object, which does expose the NDR recipients.

Comment: I cannot use Redemption because of security and firewalls in my company preventing me from setting it up.

Comment: Then it is either parsing the NDR body or Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [ReportItem.Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reportitem.body) property value and try to extract that information from that string. The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. Be aware, in some cases you need to choose the correct encoding for that, see [VSTO ReportItem.Body appeared garbled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62402904/vsto-reportitem-body-appeared-garbled) for more information.